# Click on space between lines in a <span> loses focus

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have `<span>` elements in a React app that listen for `onKeyUp` and process the text that the user selected.

If the user clicks exactly between two lines of text in the same `<span>` then the focus shifts from the `<span>` to `<body>`. For example, in this picture, clicking on the big gaping whitespace between the lines shifts the focus to the body instead of the parent element:

[image: a sentence with a large space between its two lines]

This is not good, because I don't want my event listener that far up (nor do I know how to put a React listener on `<body>`, which I don't want to do).

Is there some CSS wizardry that would preserve the line spacing, but make the entire space between two lines belong to either the top or bottom line?

Comment: What is causing that space between the lines? The [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property or something else?

Comment: does the focus issue occur if you set the span to a display type of block?

Comment: Why cant the `span`s parent catch that event? It doesn't have to go up all the way to `body`.

Comment: Do you have a live example with the CSS you're working with?